# Unable to onclick dynamic generated html element from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

I have servlet that creates html elements and returns as text/html

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    
out.write("<span class='tagged-time'> <a href='#' id='" + current.getSecond() + "' class='time'>" + current.getName() +"</a></span>");
```

In Jsp, I call this servlet using AJAX. It return the html elements properly but when I click, the onclick method is not called.

```
$('.tagged-time').on('click', 'a', function() {
    video.currentTime = this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the `tagged-time` element also is created dynamically, you need bind the handler to a element which is present at the time of event binding - in this case `tagged-time` element is not

```
$(document).on('click', '.tagged-time a', function() {
    video.currentTime = this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you bind the event onclick with jquery, it only bind the event with existing stuff on your page. So even if you render one more .tagged-time later, the new tag is not binded by prevous bind command.

What you can try is, let your servlet also return a simple javascript line that bind the new element with event handler every time you return the new .